# GOST ENGINE в CURL ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, curl, openssl

Следуя инструкциям различных ресурсов, я собирал несколько версий OPENSSL с поддержкой GOST-engine, в итоге получилось с версией 1.0.2g, затем таким же образом собирал

несколько версий cURL, собрав cURL под версию OPENSSL 1.0.2g при выводе команды

```
curl --engine
Build-time engines:
  dynamic
```

Однако при

```
openssl engine
(dynamic) Dynamic engine loading support
(gost) Reference implementation of GOST engine
```

Версии сборок:

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016

curl --version
curl 7.60.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2g zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2018-05-16
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

При этом в openssl ciphers параметры с gost-имеются, cURL собирал с командой --with-ssl с ссылкой на актуальную версию openssl, --with-zlib.

Как добавить поддержку gost в curl?

Comment: попробуйте openssl/curl в docker собранные: ``docker run --rm -v `pwd`:`pwd` -w `pwd` rnix/openssl-gost openssl version``